# how to change bibbliography title from "References" to "DAFTAR PUSTAKA"?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I want to change "References" with "DAFTAR PUSTAKA" on bibliography. I used this code to change it but it doesn't work on my file. My fried tell me that it is work on her thesis.

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{DAFTAR PUSTAKA}

\bibliography{Referensi}
```

[image]

Comment: Depending on the class and other packages, `\bibname` might not be used in the bibliography environment etc. all; perhaps it is hard coded as `References` there, so any change of `bibname` is not getting what you want. As long as you do not post the minimal version of your document, that has this issue, there is not much help, I fear

Comment: try `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\bibname}{DAFTAR PUSTAKA}}`

Answer (score 1):

You should add `babel` support for Indonesian.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{uthor,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2018,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[indonesian]{babel}

\begin{document}

\section{Indonesia}

Republik Indonesia (RI) atau Negara Kesatuan Republik Indonesia (NKRI), 
atau lebih umum disebut Indonesia, adalah negara di Asia Tenggara yang 
dilintasi garis khatulistiwa dan berada di antara daratan benua Asia dan 
Australia, serta antara Samudra Pasifik dan Samudra Hindia~\cite{uthor}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to change the title for the references to “DAFTAR PUSTAKA”, then add the relevant information: the correct command to redefine is `\refname` when the document class is `article`; it is `\bibname` for `report` or `book`. Other classes may differ.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{uthor,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2018,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[indonesian]{babel}

\addto\captionsindonesian{\renewcommand{\refname}{DAFTAR PUSTAKA}}

\begin{document}

\section{Indonesia}

Republik Indonesia (RI) atau Negara Kesatuan Republik Indonesia (NKRI), 
atau lebih umum disebut Indonesia, adalah negara di Asia Tenggara yang 
dilintasi garis khatulistiwa dan berada di antara daratan benua Asia dan 
Australia, serta antara Samudra Pasifik dan Samudra Hindia~\cite{uthor}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notes: the text is from [Indonesian Wikipedia](https://id.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indonesia); the `filecontents*` environment is used only for making the example self-contained.